# Kotlin top level function with private java contructor

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the kotlin file with top level function and specified name for using it from java code:

**Utility.kt**

```
@file:JvmName("Utility")
package com.example

fun someUtilityFunc() {
    // ignored
}
```

and I can instantiate `Utility` class in my Java code:

**Main.java**

```java
package com.example;

public Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Utility();
    }
}
```

How can I add the private constructor to generated `Utility` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `file:JvmName` will generate a regular class with static methods.

If you absolutely don't want to have this constructor, you'll have to use `object`

```
object Utility {
    fun someUtilityFunc() {
    // ignored
    }
}
```

Now previously, you could just called `someUtilityFunc()` in your Kotlin code, and it just worked.

But thankfully you can import functions in Kotlin, so it still works without prefixing:

```
import com.example.Utility.someUtilityFunc

fun main() {
    someUtilityFunc()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `object` keyword generates java singleton, with INCTANCE variable and instantiate it inside. So we have no way to create analogue java utility classes in kotlin, because in java we can create utility class without instantiating it and without possibilities instantiating. It's unfortunate